# Webstorm Live Update port number randomly changes, error :net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: javascript, ide, webstorm

Currently using webstorm version 9.0.1. Whenever the javascript project is debug by clicking run->Debug'project name', follwing error is encountered,
GET http://localhost:63342/events/events.html net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED,
the port number on which live update is working is different than the one specified in the above get request, it is randomly selected by WebStorm every time webstorm instance is restarted, what could be a solution to this?

Comment: I'm also facing this problem. Do you have a solution to this?

Comment: not yet, all that I can do is navigate to the random port number every time to view the live update.

Comment: I'll try my best to find the solution. It's troublesome to keep changing port.